# Layout на пол-экрана, как сделать

Tags: android, xml

Есть xml-файл. В нем есть RelativeLayout, а уж в нем еще 2 RelativeLayout'a (Красный и синий)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Высота последних должна быть равна половине высоты экрана телефона. То есть - пол-экрана красным, пол-экрана синим) Возможно? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделайте родительский контейнер LinearLayout-ом и задайте одинаковые веса потомкам.

Либо программно измерьте экран и задайте параметры в рантайме

Либо используйте PercentLayout